# How to format url datetime parameter with timezone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, utc, timezone-offset

I've searched everywhere and can't find the answer. I would like to understand what's going with the way I format the datetime (with timezone) url parameter.

Here is the situation:

1. The caller program is having DateTime value with UTC timezone.
2. The receiver Json WebAPI (C#) is running on my local pc which is having Central timezone.
3. The PoCreationDate is a DateTime type (C#). I do not write code to parse the PoCreationDate value. C# converted it to DateTime object for me auto-magically (thru Serialization?).

Here are the test cases:

**Case 1**:
This one works

http://******/api/ItemSource/GetItemSourceOption?OrganizationCode=OKC&PoCreationDate=2018-10-08T01:02:03.0000000-05:00

**Case 2**:
This one does not work and the browser is displaying

```
<Error>
    <Message>The request is invalid.</Message>
</Error>
```

http://******/api/ItemSource/GetItemSourceOption?OrganizationCode=OKC&PoCreationDate=2018-10-08T05:00:00.0000000+00:00

Notice the different? one of them have a -05:00 the other have +00:00. My timezone is Central (which is -05:00 right now?)

**Case 3**:
My current work around is to format it this way
http://******/api/ItemSource/GetItemSourceOption?OrganizationCode=OKC&PoCreationDate=2018-10-08T05:00:00**Z**

=====================

So I am just trying to understand what's going on here and these my thoughts...

I believe that using the Z format is the best solution since the DateTime value (from the source) is always in UTC format.

About the -05:00 and +00:00, are these supposed to be set per the receiver's timezone (the destination Server local timezone)? So for this case, my PC is the receiver (WebAPI) and it's set to Central Time Zone, therefore this value must be -05:00 to represent the current value for Central Time Zone?

Please help me understand this. Thanks.

Comment: Well if you think you're having fun now, wait for the daylight saving time to kick in (or out, depending on where you are on the planet)... date time + time zone issues are hard...

Comment: I don't think of this as an answer, but more of a way to help you find a good solution. One trick I do is pass my date/time as two parameters. The first parameter is the date/time as a file time (a long value) and the second parameter is the time zone or local that it is in. This way you can convert it to the appropriate value in background. Also, save your self a headache or two, store all of your date/time as UTC. It will be easier to convert it to the local time that way.

Comment: I know what you're saying... but with this method, you do not have to write any code to convert strings to DateTime. The serialization process will do that for you automatically.

Comment: About the -05:00 and +00:00, are these supposed to be set per the receiver's timezone (the destination Server local timezone)? So for this case, my PC is the receiver (WebAPI) and it's set to Central Time Zone, therefore this value must be -05:00 to represent the current value for Central Time Zone?
<<<<
About this part of my question, the -05:00 or +00:00 is stating the timezone offset from the caller side. I believe that's the correct understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` character in the offset is being interpreted as a space, as per URL encoding rules.  You will need to encode it, such that it is replaced with `%2B`.

- If you are building this URL from JavaScript, use the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function.
- If you are building it in C#, use the [`System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/eu-es/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode) method.

Note that doing so will also replace the `:` characters with `%3A`, which is optional in a querystring parameter, but still recommended.

In general, parameters passed in the querystring need to be encoded, unless you can guarantee that they contain no special characters.

Also, you may want to ask yourself if this field really needs to be a full date+time+offset.  In many cases, one might expect a field like `PoCreationDate` to be *just* a date, as in `"2018-10-08"`.   Of course, that depends on your application logic and business requirements.

Comment: OMG... how could I forget about the Encoding part. You're absolutely correct sir. Once I changed the +to %2B and it works just fine. Thank you :-)