# How to take "date+time+timezones" parameter in REST API

Tags: c#, rest, http

I am having problem getting "date+time+timezones" in my C# Rest API code.

The get method is defined like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id, DateTimeOffset start, DateTimeOffset stop)
```

When I am sending something like:
http://localhost:xxx/api/id/request?start=2021-02-18T13:30:00Z&stop=2021-02-18T13:35:00Z

I can properly get the start and stop time.

However, when sending the request like:
http://localhost:xxx/api/id/request??start=2021-02-18T15:30:00+02:00&stop=2021-02-18T15:35:00+02:00

With the timezone info at the end of date and time, I am not able to get the request in my code, can anyone let me know what type of object I need to use instead of "DateTimeOffset" to properly get this format of time?

Comment: Your types are correct. I assume the reason is that a plus sign in the query part of an URI is treated as a replacement character for a space. Therefore you would need to percent-encode the plus sign.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993449/how-to-format-url-datetime-parameter-with-timezone

Comment: Therefore: if you create your in URI in C# you need to encode query parameters by using Uri.EncodeDataString so they get properly percent-encoded, i.e. a + would be replaced by %2B.

Comment: Hi guys, I understand the encode, now the problem is, my project is a C# REST API which could only receive the http request from client that cannot be modified, it is always with +. I am wondering are there anything I can add in my code such as in front of Get method to receive this http request. Now that request with + cannot get into this method.